# Trying to create a new action in a backend module: "Action "module/show" does not exist."

Tags: symfony1

i have created a new action called executeDetagli() in backend/modules/ordini/actions/actions.class.php.

When I try to go to "backend_dev.php/ordini/detagli" It gives me this error:

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
>   Action "ordini/show" does not exist.
>   stack trace
>
> ```
> * at ()
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfController.class.php
> ```
>
> line 192 ...
>                189.         $this->dispatcher->notify(new
>   sfEvent($this, 'application.log',
>   array(sprintf('Action "%s/%s" does not
>   exist', $moduleName, $actionName))));
>                190.       }
>                191.
>
> ```
>          192.       throw new sfError404Exception(sprintf('Action
> ```
>
> "%s/%s" does not exist.', $moduleName,
>   $actionName));
>                193.     }
>                194.
>
> ```
>          195.     // create an instance of the action
> * at sfController->forward('ordini',
> ```
>
> 'show')
>         in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfFrontWebController.class.php
>   line 48 ...
>                 45.       }
>                 46.
>
> ```
>           47.       // make the first request
>           48.       $this->forward($moduleName,
> ```
>
> $actionName);
>                 49.     }
>                 50.     catch (sfException $e)
>                 51.     {
>       * at sfFrontWebController->dispatch()
>         in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfContext.class.php
>   line 170 ...
>                167.    */
>                168.   public function dispatch()
>                169.   {
>                170.     $this->getController()->dispatch();
>                171.   }
>                172.
>
> ```
>          173.   /**
> * at sfContext->dispatch()
>   in SF_ROOT_DIR/web/backend_dev.php line
> ```
>
> 13 ...
>                 10. require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
>                 11.
>
> ```
>           12. $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('backend',
> ```
>
> 'dev', true);
>                 13. sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
>                 14.

I have this in routing.yml:

```
shop_order:
  class: sfPropelRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                ShopOrder
    module:               ordini
    prefix_path:          /ordini
    column:               orders_id
    with_wildcard_routes: true


default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Any idea?

sf 1.4/propel

Javi

Answer (score 0):

Try :

- `symfony cc`
- ensure that the view **.../modules/ordini/templates/detagliSuccess.php** exists

Answer to your comment : in your **routing.yml**, try to add a routing rule like the following one, *just before* the final rule, to match the `module/action` pattern without the trailing slash (since I guess that the `ordini/detagli` action won't match the first rule) :

```
default_noslash:
  url:   /:module/:action
```

As well, there are plenty of solutions which you can get with a few Googling :

http://blog.phpleo.com/2008/01/27/redireccion-301-en-symfony-filtros-vs-htaccess/

http://www.decentmind.com/2010/07/symfony-without-a-slash-at-the-tail/

etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do that, but it doesn't works. I have realized that it works perfect when i add "/" at the end of the url, but why??? I don't have any problem to go to the New action just using "backend_dev.php/ordini/new".